# База данных: не могу разобраться, что делать со строкой подключения

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Помогите собрать проект.
На одном ПК, выдает ошибку о том что не удается найти БД, а на другом ошибки версий 752//852.
Проект уже собран, не понимаю что делать с SqlConnection.
С#/SQLExpress2012/SqlConnection
[Проект](https://yadi.sk/d/bLFE-9gNZ6_brg)

Comment: не надо никаких ссылок, пишите всё, что относится к вопросу, прямо в вопрос.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Строка подключения к СУБД может различаться на каждом компьютере. Поэтому её выносят в конфиг, файл настроек и т. п. И задают её при установке приложения. Она не должна быть зашита в код.

Comment: Здесь собраны практически все случаи https://www.connectionstrings.com/